# What is VSTO architecture & design? Can it be used for export/Import of an excel file from asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, vsto, ms-office, export-to-excel

In asp.net web application, I have implemented export to Excel feature, here for few of the row values I need to show text in excel with the font attributes i.e. Render HTML.
If i use xls format then this works perfectly fine but when i use xlsx as the file type then HTML is not rendered while data is exported in  excel, however the HTML tags are displayed as it is in exported excel file.
    To resolve this one of the suggestion i recieved is use VSTO architecture & design.   But when i researched on this it looks irrelevant to me.. VSTO is for adding plugin in   Microsoft Office tools and not for something to be worked in web application.
    Can someone please guide me with VSTO APIS for this functionality and also if there is   any other option available to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Excel Interop and therefore VSTO is not supported for server-side applications such as asp.net](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Consider using a 3rd party product such as Aspose or Epplus.

Comment: Thanks Joe, will the OpenXML suggested in given link resolve the issue with HTML rendering within excel with xlsx format?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you are trying to automate Excel on your server.

Try using [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)
Simple example creating excel spreadsheet is [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2013/03/04/how-to-use-the-open-xml-sdk-2-0-in-visual-studio-2010-to-create-a-simple-excel-spreadsheet-in-c.aspx).
Some more [How Do I for Spreadsheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850837.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Kitu, I will try these examples and OpenXML as solution. Just one quick question, will the OpenXML resolve the issue with HTML rendering within excel with xlsx format?

Comment: Hi Kiru, With OPEN XML also, I do not see a way to add formating to cell value. Here formating means adding html to enable font attributes for text.

Comment: I dont think you can use HTML to add styles in Open XML. Unfortunately you need to convert the HTML styles to its equivalent in Open XML. Its really pain I found this http://html2openxml.codeplex.com/ which might help you. I havent used this before so no idea how this works.

Comment: Here is the specification for Open XML. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

Comment: but this is complete HTML conversion to Open XML, the main issue I am facing is applying font attubutes to the cell values.. When I have html in cell value, with xlsx format, it does not render the html but for xls format it works fine.

Comment: As said formatting is a pain and going to take hell lot of time. If possible trying to use a template so you can haven all formatting in your template already and just add the data.

Comment: i.e. XSLT for styling?

Comment: Check this http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2012/04/26/all-about-styles-in-spreadsheetml.aspx